How can I push a partial clone (blobless) to a new remote, without fetching and pushing all the blobs?
This does not dupe Why can't I push from a shallow clone?, because I am asking specifically about partial clones. No use of --depth here.
Starting with a "blobless" clone:
git clone --filter=blob:none https://example.com/a-repo.git

I have added a new remote (it exists, and is empty) called lite
git remote add lite https://example.com/b-repo.git

A git push -u lite HEAD gets all the blobs from origin and pushes all the blobs to lite. At least, that's what I think it was doing because it printed out the origin url and tried to push a lot of objects. (Verified with a toy example using file:// remotes.)
Can I only push the commits, trees and currently available blobs to lite? That is, can I just push what I've got in a-repo without pulling from origin?
If I git remote remove origin, then git has fits:
GSLAL0320120132 % git push --verbose lite                                                                                                                                   23T20:24
Pushing to file://Users/Ian/b-repo
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
fatal: unable to read 5c20a7a001d205148607809eacabc4b3405d1aa0
error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
To file:///Users/icarroll/tmp/c-repo
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'file:///Users/Ian/b-repo'


I'm going to guess that the answer is "no".
I think the way to look at this is that the repo on your local machine is defective; it makes reference to blobs that it is supposed to have but doesn't. It is surprising that Git permits this at all, and it does so only because when it sees that it needs to fulfill a missing blob reference, it fetches it from origin.
Well, in order to push to a new remote, it needs to fulfill all the blob references. When you cut the repo off from origin, it can't do that, so it can't push.

Disappointing, but I think you're right. I guess it is risking too much to pass those pac-*.promisor files around.
